# How to enter and submit value in the JavaScript textbox via Excel VBA

Tags: javascript, html, vba, excel

Despite extensive searching for the answer to my question I was not able to find it.

What I would like to achieve is to enter a value into a textbox which is apparently part of JavaSctipt embedded into webpage. After value is entered, I want to submit it (via Call or Put button - look at the linked webpage).

All above I want to code in VBA Excel environment.

I know how to control webpage via VBA if it is simply html site without any javascripts.

Site I am working with: https://eu.bancdebinary.com//

What I want to execute:

[image: bancdebinary.com_screenshot]

Appreciate any help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to interact with DOM elements directly, here is an example of simple IE automation (for me it shows "open account" dialog since I have not got account and clicked call button):

```
Option Explicit

Sub ClickCallBtn()
    Dim objIE, objTradeBox, objPositionForm, objAmount, colButtons, objButton
    ' navigate to the page
    Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    objIE.Visible = True
    objIE.navigate "https://eu.bancdebinary.com/"
    ' wait until page state is complete
    Do While objIE.busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
    Do While objIE.document.readyState <> "complete"
        DoEvents
    Loop
    ' wait until first trade box is ready
    Do Until TypeName(objIE.document.getElementById("binaryEntity_0")) = "HTMLDivElement"
        DoEvents
    Loop
    ' get necessary controls
    Set objTradeBox = objIE.document.getElementById("binaryEntity_0")
    Set objPositionForm = objTradeBox.getElementsByTagName("form")(0)
    Set objAmount = objPositionForm.amount
    Set colButtons = objTradeBox.getElementsByTagName("button")
    ' set amount value
    objAmount.Value = 10
    ' search call button and click it
    For Each objButton In colButtons
        If objButton.innerText = "Call" Then
            objButton.Click
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```